# Prepared statement not executing under lock

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm finding I can't execute a prepared statement under a table lock, the page locks up as though the command is waiting for release and I have to manually kill the lock.

This is just an example case:

```
mysql_query("LOCK TABLE TBL WRITE");

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO TBL (ID) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $nextID);
$stmt->execute();

mysql_query("UNLOCK TABLES");
```

Is there a reason why this would be the case? Before introducing prepared statements it worked fine as does the execution without the lock.
This is just for learning purposes so please no comments on why it needs to be locked and auto-incremented ID's :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

`mysql_query` but  `$mysqli->prepare`

You are locking your table in the connection established by `mysql_connect`
No wonder the table got locked in all other connections, included one created by mysqli.

Comment: how interesting. So doing so would be an actual manner to simulate parallel transactions... I wonder if it happens 100% of the time

Comment: @sebas: yes, it would. pdo, mysql, mysqli are all internally independent. a connection established in one is not shareable/usable with the others. And two+ connections established within the same library are also independent of each other. locks in connection 'a' will lock out anything in connection 'b'.

Comment: Marc, no, because mysql internally chooses which connection to use, not us. I made many tests on this since I'm implementing a transactional system under mysql. The only safe way to ensure independent sessions (within one library only) is to use different users. Try it, you will be surprised to see that 2 different users on 2 different pc *may* share the lock

Comment: @Sebas you are talking of persistent connections probably, that *may* have some pitfalls of the kind. But with regular connection they are perfectly distinct and clean. And mysqli is using mysql_change_user() function which makes every connection clean and safe even when using pconnect. I made many tests on this since I was trying to make prepared statements work between separate calls %)

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm working with PDO, would it make a difference? The only way I found in obscure advanced php pages to ensure clean and safe parallel connections was to rebuild php with a custom parameter

Comment: @MarcB, my comment was indeed related to persistent connection, please ignore it

Comment: @Sebas well it's all of persistent. AFAIK, PDO doesn't clean it. I'd just refrain from using persistent in your case

Comment: @YourCommonSense, I'm implementing transversal transactions that persist through different scripts so that's my only solution

Answer (score 1):

You are using two different connections when you use mysqli AND mysql. Use the one OR the other. (Only the connection (mysql in this case) who has locked can write.)

Here you lock the other connection from writing.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute the `INSERT` query because the `LOCK` statement is executed on a different mysql session .

From what i can tell you have 2 mysql sessions :
  1. using build-in mysql functions like `mysql_query`
  2. using a library to connect to mysql `$stmt->execute();`

So try using the **same** mysql session.